# Is there a way to send a copied link to my discord channel through a bot?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, bots, pyautogui

I am new to python and discord bots, So I am sorry if this is a stupid question or my way of handling it is not right. My goal was to make a bot that can open an instant google meet and send me the link on discord. I was able to achieve the first part of the goal, that is, I was able to programme the bot to open chrome and go to the google meet website using `os.system`

```
os.system('chrome meet.google.com')
```

I had to set the path to chrome.exe in Environment Variables. From there I used `pyautogui` to start a meeting. After that, the bot automatically copies the link to the meeting.

Now, this is the part I am stuck in, I don't know how to send this link through the bot to my discord.

I thought of using a separate python program that runs simultaneously. The first program first adds the link in the second program's code and then executes it in cmd. The second program's job would be to just send a message. But I would like to know if there's any easier way of doing this.

Thank you for anyone replying.

I am using **Python 3.9** and **discord.py 1.7.2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Selenium a Python package for controlling web browser. Pyautogui is mostly used to control the keyboard and mouse so you cannot use it to send the link to discord. Selenium is used for this purpose.
You can learn more about it using the following links:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/selenium-python-introduction-and-installation/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/selenium-python-tutorial/

https://pypi.org/project/selenium/